# How to update stylesheet on each page request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms, updatepanel

In my ASP.NET WebForms project I need to update stylesheet on each page request.

No problem for now - I added css.ashx handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
            Random r = new Random();
            int red = r.Next(0, 255);
            int green = r.Next(0, 255);
            int blue = r.Next(0, 255);

            string css = string.Format("body {{ background-color: rgba({0}, {1}, {2}, 1); }}", red, green, blue);
            context.Response.Write(css);
        }
```

and put it to Master page:

```
<link href="/Scripts/css.ashx?tmp=<%=(new Random()).Next() %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Still no problems. Css will be loaded per each request.

Problems appear with UpdatePanels:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="btnOk_Click" ID="btnOk" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Pressing on "Update" button, css will not be updated.
It's correct behavior, but I need to find work around.

My suggestion is to move 
`<link href="/Scripts/css.ashx" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` block to another `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode="Always"` in MasterPage:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <link href="/Scripts/css.ashx?tmp=<%=(new Random()).Next() %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It works perfectly, but I can add this block in form element only.
In result I have invalid HTML document (link element located in body, not head).

How can I prevent it? Any ideas?
I don't want to register javascript per each request to update link href.

Comment: On each request are you sure? There must be some condition on which you might be changing the style-sheet?

Comment: @Shekhar Ok. It will be based on cookies variable for example.